# Web ex security

Tags: webex

Is it secure to share your desktop over a Web Ex connection? For example, if you open a Microsoft Word document then is there a risk that anyone can view it or just the intended audience?

I have looked online for an answer and I came across this: http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/wp_security.pdf, though it does not specifically answer my question.

Comment: probably would be best to pose this question to the webex people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The company I work for uses WebEx on a daily basis for meetings and sharing sessions, including that are considered to have security concerns. The following article is available which speaks about WebEx security methods.

http://www.webex.com.hk/en/pdf/wp_security_overview.pdf

Comment: Thanks, Before I accept your answer, could you explain what you mean by: "including that are considered to have security concerns"

Comment: Sorry, unclear, best way to put it is meetings our company has dealing with very "sensitive" information.

Comment: Thanks, are you saying that it is secure to share a desktop and display sensitive information as a presenter? I am thinking about using this tool.

Comment: Yes, in addition most companies will also secure their network perimeter. Or requiring the ability to VPN to the network to obtain access to something internal such as WebEx

Comment: I work for a large organisation and we have a firewall.  Is that what you mean by: "most companies will also secure their network perimeter".  I assume that it is safe to show personal info on screen as well when sharing the desktop?

Comment: Yes, and yes.  There are many ways to secure your networks perimeter, and this is up to your network team on how they wish to do this.  The PDF contains a lot of helpful information for you to answer most of these questions.

Comment: What does securing the perimeter have to do with my question? Sorry if I sound naive.  I am almost ready to mark as answered.